# Why is my spawner changing into a pig spawner after its first spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to spawn a large amount of llama spit constantly. Currently, I'm using this command:

```
give @p minecraft:spawner
{
  BlockEntityTag: {
    SpawnCount: 100,
    MaxNearbyEntities: 20,
    SpawnRange: 30,
    Delay: 10,
    MinSpawnDelay: 1,
    MaxSpawnDelay: 2,
    RequiredPlayerRange: 50,
    SpawnData: {
      id: "minecraft:llama_spit",
      CustomName:"\"Subzero Hail\"",
      CustomNameVisible:1,
      Attributes: [
        {Name: "generic.followRange", Base: 500},
        {Name: "generic.knockbackResistance", Base: 1f},
        {Name: "generic.movementSpeed", Base: 0.5f}
      ],
      ActiveEffects: [
        {Id: 5, Amplifier: 2, Duration: 2147483647}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When given to me and placed down it spawns in the llama spit correctly but after it summons in the first wave of llama spit the spawner changes into a pig spawner. How do I fix this to make it keep spawning the llama spit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, you are probably making a game that involves sub-zero hail attacking right? well I think you can just use the `summon` command to summon a lot. if you don't want it spawning at the speed of repeat command blocks, use a redstone timer. if you want to spawn the llama spit at a random time, use `execute at @e[type=armor_stand, limit=1, sort=random, tag=spit] run setblock ~ ~ ~ redstone_block` and then add some armor stands with the tag spit which only one of them with the summon command.

Edit: lol I just noticed that the question is why it turns into a pig spawner, but still, I think you should use the `summon` method because then you can choose when to start summoning and if you want the player to actually *see* the spawner I think you can just use a texture pack

Comment: You can also use the repeat command block value "Delay in Ticks" to change how often it runs from 1r/tick to 1r/x ticks instead of a redstone timer.